# Ellipsisze textView that is more than 2 lines inside a widget

Tags: android, textview, android-appwidget

The ellipsize option always considers the second line of the textview. Is there a way to solve this problem for a textview inside an app widget.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ellipsizing does not work with more than 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer Romain. I'm fan of your work since swing :).

Comment: You need to add this limitation to the official documentation

Comment: No because if we do it will become part of the API :)